# Randomly choosing items from lists and storing the index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 60 films.

```
films = ['x','y','z' ......]
```

I want to randomly choose 5 of these films for the user to rate (from -5 to 5) and for these ratings to be stored in a new list in the same index that the film holds in the  list of films.

For example, if the 5 films were in the 0th, 12th, 15th,25th and 56th index then they would be in these positions in my new list and the rest of the items in the  list would be zeros. So it would look something like

```
'Please rate the following films:'
harry potter: 3 #user inputs rating of 3 and so on
inception: 5
Disaster Move: -5
saw 2: 2 
interstellar: 4
```

For convenience, let's say that the films happen to be the 0th,2nd,4th,5th and 7th indexes in the list of films

```
 print(results)
 [3,0,5,0,-5,2,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,......] #all the way to 60 ratings
```

Okay so now i get

```
ratings[books.index(books[i])]=rate
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment
```

my code looks like:

```
books = []
with open('books.txt') as b:
    for line in b:
        books.append(line)

if username in namesToRatings:
    print('We already have your data')
    userdata = {username:namesToRatings[username]}
else:
    print('We dont have your data')
    random_index=random.sample(range(0,59), 5)
    print(random_index)
    for i in random_index:
        rate=input(books[i]+" : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5")
        ratings[books.index(books[i])]=rate
        print(ratings)
```

Comment: You _can_ do this, but… are you sure you want to? A dict mapping films to ratings, or a list of (film, rating) pairs, or a list of Film objects with a rating attribute might be a better design.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Which part are you stuck on? Do you know how to randomly choose 5 elements out of a list? (If not, see the `random` docs; there are nice examples.) Do you know how to create a list of 0's the same size as an existing list? Are you just stuck keeping track of the index together with the film? (Look up `enumerate`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import string
films = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5)) for i in range(60)] #Generating 60 random string
ratings = [0 for i in range(60)] #Generating List of 60 Zeros
random_index=random.sample(range(0,59), 5)
print(random_index)
for i in random_index:
  rate=input(films[i]+" : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5:")
  ratings[films.index(films[i])]=rate
print(ratings)
```

Corrected Your code:

```
import random
books = []
ratings = [0 for i in range(60)]
with open('books.txt') as b:
    for line in b:
        books.append(line.strip())
if username in namesToRatings:
    print('We already have your data')
    userdata = {username:namesToRatings[username]}
else:
    print('We dont have your data')
    random_index=random.sample(range(0,59), 5)
    print(random_index)
    for i in random_index:
      rate=input(books[i]+" : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5")
      ratings[books.index(books[i])]=rate
      print(ratings)
```

Comment: I used with open('films.txt') as f and stored each film in a list. Now when I try to give a rating from -5 to -5 i get: ratings[books.index(books[i])]=rate
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment

Comment: where is your ratings list

Comment: When I run the program now the films titles arnt right. E.g 2T3T6 : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5 ; AKCK3 : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5 ; HDTX8 : Give Rating for this film from -5 to 5. Ill try the code you corrected

Comment: my above code is generating random string of combination uppercase lowercase and digit that's why you are getting these names

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store values relative to the films

```
import random
films = ['Titanic', 'Hot Fuzz', 'RED', 'Inception', 'Waffles'] #for example
films_dict = {} #the key of the dictionary will be the film title, and the value of the key will be the rating the user gives, we will initialize the entries with a rating of 0.
for film in films:
    films[film] = 0 #create dictionary from existing list of films
for i in range(5): #ask the user 5 times to rate 5 different films and store their rating as a value to the key (films name) in our dictionary)
    film_to_rate = random.choice(films)
    rate = input('Please rate this film :', film_to_rate)
    films_dict[film_to_rate] = rate
```

Whilst this solution works to generate random films to rate, the problem is that the user may be asked to rate the same film twice, you could use an if else statement to check if the film has already been rated, and if it has randomly choose another film to rate, however I will leave that to you.

If you want to view the rating and the movie do...

```
for key, value in films_dict:
    print(key, value)
```

I suggest using a dictionary to handle these type of things, they are a lot easier to manipulate rather than using two different lists which are connected element to element in context, a problem in one causes a problem in the other.

Comment: use `random.sample(...,k=5)` - it draws 5 from the iterable without replacement and foreach result take a rating. You havent solved the index / rating problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the part you're stuck on is how to keep track of the films, and the indexes of those films, at the same time.

If so, the trick is `enumerate`:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for idx, value in enumerate(a): print(idx, value)
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

So, however you were randomly picking 5 of the films, pick them from `enumerate(films)`.

The tricky bit is that many of the ways of picking random numbers require an actual sequence, while `enumerate` is not a sequence. If you get an error like `TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.`, what you'll want to do is create a temporary list of the enumerated pairs:

```
enumerated_films = list(enumerate(films))
```

And now, whatever you were using to pick 5 random films, you'll get 5 random (index, film) pairs instead. After that, everything should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Siplyfied version:

```
import random

films = [str(x) for x in range(1000,1000+60*50,50)] # 60 names 

# enumerate the names [ (0,'1000'),(1,'1050'),(2,'1100'),...,(58,'3900'), (59,'3950') ]
# sample 5 of the tuples (random choosing 5 without replacement)
# store int(input()) for the rating as (idx,rating) in a list
ratings = [(idx,int(input(f'\nRating for: {num}\t'))) for idx,num in \
           random.sample(list(enumerate(films)),k=5)]

# create enough zeros
zerofilled = [0 for x in range(len(films))]
# add all ratings to the zerofilled list
for idx,rat in ratings:
    zerofilled[idx]+=rat 

print(films)
print(zerofilled)
```

Output:

```
Rating for: 1500    8
Rating for: 1400    12
Rating for: 3150    9
Rating for: 1600    22
Rating for: 2450    3

['1000', '1050', '1100', '1150', '1200', '1250', '1300', '1350', 
 '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1600', '1650', '1700', '1750', 
 '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '2000', '2050', '2100', '2150', 
 '2200', '2250', '2300', '2350', '2400', '2450', '2500', '2550', 
 '2600', '2650', '2700', '2750', '2800', '2850', '2900', '2950', 
 '3000', '3050', '3100', '3150', '3200', '3250', '3300', '3350', 
 '3400', '3450', '3500', '3550', '3600', '3650', '3700', '3750', 
 '3800', '3850', '3900', '3950']

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 12, 0, 8, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Users are notorious for failed inputs, so you might want to not do it as 1-line list comp.